How can Lie algebra cohomology be nontrivial for a semisimple algebra?
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over an (algebraically closed) field $k$ of characteristic zero. I am going by the definitions in Weibel, chapter 7. Here's my logic:

A finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module is the same thing as a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ over $k$.
By Weyl's theorem, the category $\mathrm{Rep} (\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple.
From 1 and 2, the category $ \mathfrak{g-}\mathbf{mod} $ of finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-modules is semisimple.
Hence, every additive functor from $ \mathfrak{g-}\mathbf{mod} $ to any other category is exact.
Thus, the higher derived functors of the functor of invariants are all zero.

However, while Whitehead's lemmas state that $H^p \left( \mathfrak{g}, M \right) = 0 $ for $p \in \left\{ 1,2 \right\}$ any module $M$, Weibel then remarks that $H^3 \left( \mathfrak{sl}_2, k \right) \cong k $. How can that be? What are the flaws in my logic?

first cohomology is the derived functor of $\hom_\mathfrak{g}(k, -)$ on the whole module category of $U(\mathfrak{g})$, not the (as you say, semisimple) category of finite-dimensional modules. Just because ext between finite-dimensional reps vanishes doesn't mean that it will vanish between all modules, e.g. Vermas provide examples of non-split short exact sequences.
